# Import third-party scripts into React/Redux application with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, loader

I've been trying for few hours to include third-party scripts files such as jQuery and Bootstrap's JavaScript file in my React/Redux application, for I need to Bootstrap's dropdown to work.

I used the repository [here](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) as base, and I can see in the `webpack.config.js` the following piece of code, which is my only clue:

```
// ------------------------------------
// Loaders
// ------------------------------------
// JavaScript / JSON
webpackConfig.module.loaders = [{
  test    : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude : /node_modules/,
  loader  : 'babel',
  query   : config.compiler_babel
}, {
  test   : /\.json$/,
  loader : 'json'
}]
```

I do not know webpack and I find nothing clear enough for me for now.
I tried including in the `index.html` file but it never finds these files, which are stored in `src/static/scripts/`

Comment: download jquery and bootstrap through npm then you don't need to do anything with webpack just import where you need it.... `npm install jquery`......`import $ from 'jquery'`

Answer (score 0):

For using jQuery, include the following in the plugins definition of webpack:

```
plugins: [
  ...
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
  }),
  ...
],
```